# What is the best way of creating Chopper Clients on Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, chopper

I'm using Chopper for http request on Flutter and as far as I know, there are two ways of creating a Chopper Client. One is adding services to its array and then expose it:

```
// my_chopper_client.dart

  static ChopperClient getClient() {
    final chopper = ChopperClient(
      baseUrl: "https://example.com/",
      services: [
        ServiceOne.create(),
        ServiceTwo.create(),
        ServiceThree.create()
      ],
      converter: JsonConverter()
    );

    return chopper;
  }

// Some other file.dart

    void login() {
      ChopperClient client = MyChopperClient.getClient();
      var serviceTwo = client.getService<ServiceTwo>();
      var resp = await serviceTwo({"email": "example@mail.io", "password": "123"});
      print(resp.body);
    }
```

And the other one is create a new instance of a Chopper client for each service:

```
// service_two.dart

  static ServiceTwo create() {
    final client = ChopperClient(
      services: [
        _$ServiceTwo(),
      ],
      converter: JsonConverter(),
    );
    
    return _$ServiceTwo(client);
  }

// some other file.dart

  void login() async {
    var serviceTwo = ServiceTwo.create();
    var resp = await serviceTwo.login({"email": "example@mail.io", "password": "123"});
    print(resp.body);
  }
```

My question is: Which way is better to get the best performance? It seems to me that the array approach may use more memory.
Thanks in advance!